# onLocationChanged only called once, not update automatically

Tags: android, android-location

In android app want to get the location by button click here is my code

```
  public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                               LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                  .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude =    location.getLatitude();
                            longitude =      location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}


/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

              this.location=location;
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

and my call function that get the Latitude,Longitude from above code.

```
double lat = gps.getLatitude();
double log = gps.getLongitude();
```

but its only give the same location even the place is changed.

any one help me...thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I looked in your code and it seems correct in all way. Can you please try it by making minimum distance to 0 as you have given min. distance 10 meter and may be you didn't moved at that much rate and your service may be taking min. distance as primary point instead of min. time.

@Dynamo: requestupdatelocation call the onLocationChanged callback method. It is not totally depending on the location assignment. location value will change as per the user location updates.

Here question is that "onLocationChanged" callback method is not getting call on given parameter.

Comment: the onLocationChanged(Location location) method is not call even location is changed .whats the problem.

Comment: @chimbu: i don't know what the exact problem in you application as your code seems perfect. In my one of application, this same code i written and it is working. Yes but one thing, if you put this code in background service, then it is not working sometimes because i faced that problem. sorry for not able to help you here. :(

Comment: another issue: when i get the Latitude,Longitude by calling my method that show the run time error that "java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   this.location = location;
}
```

and also try reducing the MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES to a least value.

Comment: another issue: when i get the Latitude,Longitude by calling my method that show the run time error that "java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread"

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. The only reason I could think of is that device is not able to get the locations. It takes a few minutes for the device to get a lock on your location so try giving it some time.

You can use `adb shell dumpsys location` to check which apps have a location listener registered and if your app is among them. It will also tell you when was the last time android got a location update. Also try running any other location app to see if this problem is with your app or the environment.

Comment: another issue: when i get the Latitude,Longitude by calling my method that show the run time error that "java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread"